# If I kill script running script running java?

Tags: linux, process, kill, spawn

If I kill gracefully (without `-9`) a script which is running another script, which is running java in turn, will java process receive kill signal by cascade?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen java not properly shutdown in this case, and become owned by init (pid 1).  I have fixed this in the past by recording the pid of the java process after it has launched, and then sending a kill -15 in a signal handler inside the bash script.

```
jpid=

trap_intr()
{
   [ ! -z "$jpid" ] && kill $jpid
}

trap trap_intr INT TERM

java -cp ... foo &
jpid=$!
wait
```

UPDATE: I forgot to put the java process in the background, and have the bash script wait on $!